# MySQL Trigger question: only trigger when a column is changed?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I don't know if this is possible, but I have a column named `active` in a table. Whenever the active column gets changed, I would like to reset the date in the `date` column, but **ONLY** if the `active` column gets changed.

If other columns are changed but not the `active` column, then the date would remain the same.

Comment: before update need to check the old value to the new value of active column , see example in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Trigger/ReferenceoldandnewvaluebycolumninabeforeupdateTrigger.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed

Answer (score 41, accepted):

something like

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     IF NEW.active <> OLD.active THEN
     SET NEW.date = '';     
     END IF;
     END
     //
```

Comment: If I want to update the date to current date would the line change to `SET NEW.date = CURDATE();` ?

Comment: if you want date yes, if  you want date+time use NOW()

Comment: Had you **set active = 1** while active was already 1 in the DB then wouldn't that be a change? I guess technically it would, because you have set the column and in database terminology it's a column change. But **NEW.active is not OLD.active**  gives you only if NEW and OLD had different values! What will you do in that case? @HaimEvgi

Comment: Isn't it better to use `<=>` instead of `<>` ?

Comment: @stack yes, although not literally, `<=>` means "equal to, where `null` is treated like a value that can be compared", so you'd need to change to `not NEW.active <=> OLD.active`

Answer (score 19):

Ran into an issue with the IF test in the #2 example. When one of the values is null the <> test returns null. This leads to the test not getting met and the action of the trigger will not get run even though the one value does not equal null at all. To fix this I came up with this test that uses <=> (NULL-safe equal). Hope this helps someone out.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updtrigger ;
$$
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger  AFTER UPDATE
    ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.active <=> OLD.active) = 0)  THEN
     SET NEW.date = '';     
     END IF;
$$
```

Comment: You can simply use the `NOT` operator instead of comparing to zero, as in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24041832/1419007. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this have `END` before the final `$$`?

Comment: @Johnglassman - why not use BEFORE instead of AFTER?

Comment: @ValterEkholm Was a long time ago, but I suspect that my own use case was an after trigger and it was not the relevant aspect of my post. I would bet the test behaves the same way regardless of the trigger action.

Comment: @JohnGlassman Ok, you seem to remember quite well after all years. I have a memory of testing "after" and when it didn't work, I posted this/that comment, but it did work (in my use case, as I remeber) when using "before". Thanks