# NULL Handling in MySQL After Update Trigger that Fires Only on Data Change

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, null

Due to reputation constraints, this is a follow-up question to [this answer to a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296438/1913816).  I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to test each field for changes while handling NULL values.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  a INT NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
  b INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  c INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  a INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  b INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  c INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES (1, 2);
```

I want a trigger whose actions occur after update only if a value is changed by the update.  So this UPDATE won't result in an INSERT:

```
UPDATE foo SET a = 1 WHERE b = 2;
```

But this UPDATE will result in an INSERT:

```
UPDATE foo SET a = 2 WHERE b = 2;
```

I have written this trigger to handle that, however I'm hoping the IF statement can be simplified.

```
DELIMITER ///
CREATE TRIGGER t_after_update_foo
AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF
      ((OLD.a <> NEW.a OR OLD.a IS NULL OR NEW.a IS NULL) AND (NEW.a IS NOT NULL OR OLD.a IS NOT NULL))
      OR
      ((OLD.b <> NEW.b OR OLD.b IS NULL OR NEW.b IS NULL) AND (NEW.b IS NOT NULL OR OLD.b IS NOT NULL))
      OR
      ((OLD.c <> NEW.c OR OLD.c IS NULL OR NEW.c IS NULL) AND (NEW.c IS NOT NULL OR OLD.c IS NOT NULL))
    THEN
      INSERT INTO bar (a, b, c) VALUES (NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c);
    END IF;
  END;
///
DELIMITER ;
```

Can the IF statement be simplified?  Or is there an easier overall solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `coalesce()`, which returns the first of its arguments that is `not null`.

```
if coalesce(old.a,'') <> coalesce(new.a,'') or
   coalesce(old.b,'') <> coalesce(new.b,'') or
   coalesce(old.c,'') <> coalesce(new.c,'')
   then
     insert ...;
   end if;
```

It can be tricky to choose the second argument.  The above example works for the common case when a, b and c are strings and when an empty string value is equivalent to a `null` value.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by comparing using the [NULL-safe equals operator `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) and then [negating the result using `NOT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not).

So,

```
((OLD.a <> NEW.a OR OLD.a IS NULL OR NEW.a IS NULL) AND (NEW.a IS NOT NULL OR OLD.a IS NOT NULL))
```

would become

```
!(OLD.a <=> NEW.a)
```

To check if any of multiple columns have changed, you could do

```
!(OLD.a <=> NEW.a AND OLD.b <=> NEW.b)
```

---

A slightly shorter alternative if you have many colums to compare, courtesy of [@dlauzon](/users/7037546/dlauzon):

```sql
!((OLD.a, OLD.b, OLD.c, ...) <=> (NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c, ...))
```

Comment: When there are many columns to check, a slightly shorter version could be: `!((OLD.a, OLD.b, OLD.c, ...) <=> (NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c, ...))`